# hard drive raw read error rate 9

Tags: hard-drive, hard-drive-recovery, smart

My main HDD is about 2.5/3 years old. All that time, it has been running with about 40-45 (temperature).

I have had a HDD failure before and it was really frustrating, I don't want that to happen again.

I was working on a project then suddenly the computer started to slow down (I had many applications running), so I closed some of them and just for precaution, I ran HDTune to read SMART.

To my surprise, It had `raw read error rate:6`, then after 1-2 minutes, it increased to `9`. I've checked SMART data like 1 week before, and it was `raw read error rate:0`.

**Is it possible that some files have been corrupted?**

**How critical is raw read error rate? I assume I have to start making backups? or start making backups ASAP?**

[image: HDTune SMART]

It's a western digital HDD.

Comment: You can do a `scandisk /f` but either way, back up!

Comment: I don't want to put any more stress, so I guess backup it is. Thank the gods that the value hasn't increased.

Comment: @Ramhound Are you reading (05) reallocated sector count? Because it has a threshold of 140 but a value of 0. I will start making backups nonetheless.

Comment: Is this a desk top? Sometimes it can be a cable. On an old pata drive, once I changed the ribbon cable the count stopped. This could be the same with SATA cable and connection. Might be wise and cheap to reseat the cable to both drive and motherboard. Would not be the case if you are talking about a laptop.

Comment: @CarlB It is a dekstop. What do you mean by reseat? Buying a new cable or making sure it is connected properly?

Comment: @user658091 I mean to disconnect and reconnect. They are fairly inexpensive so a replacement may not be a bad idea. This also happened to a SATA DVD drive and I found a small cut from the side of the case that was giving me a hard time. I did not notice it until I pulled all the SATA cables and replaced them.